# column is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type integer

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

I get error message like below , when I create this table just like others set column timestamp `timestamp without time zone NOT NULL` , but when I tried to insert `2015-08-16 18:51:05` to this table,  then I get error, but other table is work, why and how to solve it?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "UserForgetPasswordPending"(
"UserForgetPasswordPendingId" SERIAL NOT NULL,
"Email" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
"TokenTimestamp" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
"Token" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("UserForgetPasswordPendingId")
);
ALTER TABLE "UserForgetPasswordPending"
  OWNER TO db_admin;
```

error

```
[error: column "TokenTimestamp" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type integer]
  name: 'error',
  length: 216,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42804',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: 'You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.',
```

insert

```
var utc = moment(new Date()).unix();
var tokenTimestamp = moment.unix(utc).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

var upsertUserForgetPasswordPending = function(userEmail, tokenTimestamp, token) {
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
    var queryInsert = 'INSERT INTO "UserForgetPasswordPending" ("Email","TokenTimestamp","Token") SELECT $1,2,$3';
    var queryUpsert = 'UPDATE "UserForgetPasswordPending" SET "TokenTimestamp" = $2, "Token" = $3 WHERE "Email" = $1';
    var query = 'WITH upsert AS ('+queryUpsert+' RETURNING *) '+queryInsert+' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM upsert)';
console.log(tokenTimestamp);
    dbClient.query(query, [userEmail,tokenTimestamp,token], function(error, result) {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        fulfill(result);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Please show the **exact** `insert` statement you are using. Unrelated, but: using quoted identifiers usually creates more problems than they are worth it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I update insert function I use,  what do you mean quoted identifiers ?? do you mean in query I use somethin like `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "UserForgetPasswordPending" ..` ? that because I use uppercase naming ...

Comment: What programming language is that? And what data type is the variable `tokenTimestamp`? Seems like you are passing an integer value there, not a timestamp.  I'm referring to the use of double quotes around identifiers, which makes them case sensitive. In the long run that usually creates more problems that they are worth (some dispute the "worthiness" of quoted identifiers in the first place).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  the variable `tokenTimestamp `  `2015-08-16 18:51:05`  should be text  not possible integer ,  and I think the error message means the column is integer  so I can't insert other type value into

Comment: No, the error message is pretty clear: "*column "TokenTimestamp" is of type timestamp without time zone but **expression is of type integer***". If the variable is a string (and not a "real" timestamp), then you need to put single quotes around the parameter - at least in plain SQL. Don't know about JavaScript though.

Comment: ohh I misunderstood, but I change the variable become `'2015-08-16 19:40:41'` still same error?

Comment: I have no idea how JavaScript passes variables, put in plain SQL this works just fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bfd35/1 Maybe it's caused by your usage of `select` instead of `values` for the INSERT statement, but I can't tell if JavaScript messes with that somehow.

Comment: You have a typo: `SELECT $1,2,$3` should be `SELECT $1,$2,$3`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This because you are inserting integer data to `time stamp` column.

Correct the following syntax:

`var queryInsert = 'INSERT INTO "UserForgetPasswordPending ("Email","TokenTimestamp","Token") SELECT $1,2,$3';`

In above query you are selecting `2` for `TokenTimestamp` that's why  you are getting this error.

you should replace `2` with some date time format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` .

For example: `'2015-08-07 05:00:01'`

Comment: I think it's even simpler: it was supposed to say `$2`, i.e. the second parameter to the prepared statement, as seen in the UPDATE query.

Comment: Please note date time format is case sensitive use yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss instead of yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 0):

For me casting the type explicitely worked.
Please note, I used joda Datetime

```
@CreatedDate
@Column(name = "created_on", updatable = false, nullable = false)
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime createdOn;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add timestamp like this '2025-08-07 05:00:01'